# Putting the current branch ahead of master after git revert

Tags: git, git-revert

I've made a few mistakes in updating my repository, starting with pushing a commit to the `master` instead of the `feature` branch.

What I've done to try and fix this is created a new `feature` branch off the updated `master`, followed by a `git revert` on the `master`.

After committing and pushing the changes `master` is now ahead of the `feature` branch by 1 commit I'd like it to be the other way around.

Is it possible to make this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already pushed the revert commit, you can simply revert-the-revert commit on your feature branch to get those changes back.

So, try this:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master # get back in sync with master
git revert master # revert-the-revert
```

For cleaner history, if you haven't pushed the `feature` branch yet, try this which will avoid the extra merge commit:

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard origin/master
git revert master # revert-the-revert
```

After performing either of those two command sequences your `feature` branch will now be ahead of `master`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit, I have pushed the revert commit. Also to clarify, I want the feature branch to contain the changes, and the master branch to not.

Comment: @Mitch gotcha. I updated my answer. In a nut-shell: revert the revert on your feature branch.